# ibatis initmapper EXTREMELY slow

Tags: performance, c#-4.0, ibatis, ibatis.net

We have chosen ibatis as our o/rm at my company (many years ago) and are generally happy with performance compared to other options. However, we have identified one service where the initmapper stage consistently takes 4 - 6 seconds. The mapper is small and we only use ibatis to map to stored procedures so there is no dynamic sql impact.

I have searched and searchad and have not found any other possible causes. Has anybody seen this type of behavior that was caused by something other than a large map file or dynamic sql generation? I'm lost and desperate!

Comment: It appears that if I map all the types (CLR and db) in the mapper I get a bump in performance. This is despite the ibatis documentation saying this is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if I map all the types (CLR and db) in the mapper I get a bump in performance. This is despite the ibatis documentation saying this is not really necessary.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer when you discover solution to your question.